# what are some meta tags that are being used with html5?

Tags: html

i like the new doctype that is being used

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and the utf-8 which is

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

what are a few others that is being used under html5 based on your experiences? 
also wondering if this new doctype html takes care of any doctype does it just guess what is being used?
also how and when do i use another charset rather than utf-8 ? thanks

Comment: 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0%

Comment: I would say that there's very little reason to ever use anything but UTF-8 in HTML.

Comment: @AgentConundrum: As far as I know, it's less about the points and more about respect.

Comment: http://www.dimensionedelta.net/webstuff/html5-meta-and-other-header-tags/

Answer (score 0):

The doctype works because browsers don't actually care what doctype you use and never followed the URL, they just check that the document specifies at least  so that they don't render in quirks mode. If you're using the XHTML5 serialisation then you can provide a URL as you used to, though you're unlikely to use XHTML5 in the real world.

You probably don't want to create new pages in anything but utf8, if you do have data that is encoded separately and you can't/won't convert it into utf8 then you can specify a different encoding with `<meta charset="charsetname">` where charsetname is an alias or name registered with [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets)

The [spec](http://developers.whatwg.org/semantics.html#the-meta-element) lists some meta tags that you can use. Basically the main one is still `<meta name="description" value="This page is about foo">`